# Update all href anchor links in folder of HTML files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webpack, gatsby

I am using Gatsbyjs to generate a static site, this outputs a folder of static HTML files.

I have a requirement to host these HTML files on Microsoft SharePoint - this requires the `.html` to be converted to `.aspx` in order for them to run.

I have a postscript which updates all `.html` to `.aspx` (this works nicely).

However, all the generated links point to the folder:

```
<a href="/folder/">link</a>
```

In order for this to work on sharepoint, I need to update every href in each html file to point to the `index.aspx` file in each folder:

```
<a href="/folder/index.aspx">link</a>
```

What's the best way to do on **post build**? Ideally, I'd like to include this as part of my post-build script. Can this be achieved with webpack? Or am I better off using something like JSDOM to loop through each file and update each of the links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better off using [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio), which is  lighter than jsdom and supports most of the jquery syntax.

```
var html = fs.readFileSync(input.html);
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
var output = $('a[href="folder"').attr('href', '/folder/index.aspx').html();
```